# Characteristic polynomial and similarity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial):  **two matrices with the same characteristic polynomial need not be similar**.

- But what is the simplest way of recognition that two matrices 
  with **the same characteristic polynomial** are however similar ?
- And .. does knowledge about the situation that two  matrices have **the
  same CP** give some specific clues about their relation or rather it is
  difficult in general case to determine such relation?
- .. maybe relation is clear only for special classes of matrices like
  in the case of, for example, orthogonal matrices $^*$?

  $^*$*In the case of, for example, 3-D orthogonal matrices it seems  that we have exactly the same number  of DOF for matrix ($3$ Euler angles for $3D$ rotation matrix) as its eigenvalues.*

Comment: I recommend reading up on "Jordan canonical forms". The complete structure of a matrix('s action on its vector space) is recorded by its Jordan form (which is a similarity invariant), and understand what that structure is will help you answer your question about what part of the structure goes missing when you take the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: @Greg That's what I want to know: Exactly as you have said "what part of the structure goes missing when you take the characteristic polynomial".